# Harmonic forms on holomorphic line bundle

Tags: complex-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $L$ be a holomorphic line bundle on a Kähler manifold $X^n$. Let $h$ be a hermitian metric on $L$ which gives us a $\mathbb{C}$-antilinear isomorphism $h:L\cong L^*.$ Next we have
\begin{align*}
\bar{*}_L:\Lambda^{p,q}X\otimes L\rightarrow \Lambda^{n-p,n-q}X\otimes L^*
\end{align*}
defined by $\bar{*}_L(\phi\otimes s)=\bar{*}(\phi)\otimes h(s)=\overline{*(\phi)}\otimes h(s)=*(\bar\phi)\otimes h(s),*$ is $\mathbb{C}$-linear on $\Lambda^{p,q}X.$

Next we define the adjoint of $\bar\partial_L$ by
\begin{align*}
\bar{\partial}^*_L:=-\bar*_{L^*}\circ \bar\partial_{L^*}\circ \bar*_L
\end{align*}
and then we call a form in $\mathcal{A}^{p,q}(E)$ harmonic if it lies in the Kernel of
\begin{align*}
\Delta_L:=\bar{\partial}^*_L\bar{\partial}_L+\bar{\partial}_L\bar{\partial}^*_L
\end{align*}
Now I had a understanding that these harmonic forms should depend on the metric $h$ on $L$, but my calculation shows that
\begin{align*}
\bar{\partial}^*_L(\phi\otimes s)&=-\bar*_{L^*}\circ \bar\partial_{L^*}\circ \bar*_L(\alpha\otimes s)\\
&=-\bar*_{L^*}\circ \bar\partial_{L^*} (*(\bar\phi)\otimes h(s))\\
&=-\bar*_{L^*}\circ (\bar\partial (*(\bar\phi))\otimes h(s))\\
&=-(*\overline{(\bar\partial (*(\bar\phi))})\otimes s\\
&=(-*\partial *(\phi))\otimes s\\
&=\bar\partial^*(\phi)\otimes s
\end{align*}

Is this calculation correct but then it says that the harmonic forms doesn't depend on the metric $h$ at all or am I making some mistake here?

Comment: "am I making some mistake here?" Yes

Comment: @YangMills can you please explain it ?